# Is there any way to stop Telegram from showing pages from my site as Instant View version?

Tags: telegram, instant-view

I run a blog and distribute my posts in a Telegram channel. One day, I got surprised that links started showing as "Instant View" versions, since I never managed to support this technology (and, tbh, I don't like it either). Later, I discovered that readers that I don't know submitted IV templates to Telegram, and eventually one of them was approved.

I searched for any way to stop Telegram converting my posts into IV version, without success. Is there any (a meta tag, a form, whatever) to ask Telegram to disable IV in links from my domain?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Instant views are implemented via a set of hardcoded XPath rules, so you can change the markup of your website (like, class/id names) or paths (`/blog/a1.html` → `/kek/a1`). It can break the rules, and IV won't be shown.

One more trick is to integrate an iframe into the body of articles (or to the end). The reason is that iframes are not supported by the IV engine (the exclusion is embedded youtube). You can set 1×1 size, to make it invisible to users.

Another trick is to integrate an image with src tag leading to some nonexistent path. Telegram server won't be able to fetch the resource, and IV generation will be failed.

Answer (score 0):

No. You can't disable instant view for your blog or site. That's just how Telegram instant view works. It will cache hundreds of sites and crop the content of the articles. You can read more about it here:

https://instantview.telegram.org/

Currently, there's a contest for instant view templates. The goal is to get as many sites working with instant view as possible.